# Ui-view doesn't update values from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a catalog.html angular application where 2 ui views and they under the same controller categoryCtrl:

**catalog.html**

```
<!-- SEARCH -->         
<div ui-view="search-catalog"></div>
<!-- CONTENT -->            
<div ui-view="result"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
.state('catalog', {
url: '/catalog',
views: {
    'search-catalog': {
      templateUrl: 'views/search-catalog.html',
      controller: 'categoryCtrl'
    },
    'result': {
      templateUrl: 'views/result.html',
      controller: 'categoryCtrl'
    },
```

When I change something in `search-catalog` and can see changes inside categoryCtrl, the changes are not reflected in `result`. In particular, I have an array $scope.items and ng-repeat does not update its values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said the categoryCtrl has been duplicated with two separate scopes, thus if you modify $scope.items object in the *search-catalog* scope will not be reflected in *result* scope.
If you don’t mind to move the logic on the parent scope (*catalog*) you could also do the following:

```
.state('catalog', {
  url: '/catalog',
  views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'catalog.html',
        controller: 'catalogCtrl'
      },

      'search-catalog@catalog': {
        templateUrl: 'views/search-catalog.html'              
      },

      'result@catalog': {
        templateUrl: 'views/result.html'              
      }
  }
```

```
.controller("catalogCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
  });
```

In this case the nested views will be bound to the same controller/scope.
If you want to separate logic between your nested views and the parent you should use a singleton like a service or factory and inject that in your nested views.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution and will let know

Comment: It is worth adding that I had to put ui-views into `catalog.html`

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is creating 2 different instances of your controller so, both controllers have separates scopes. The changes you make in one of them is not reflected in the other.

There are different ways to achieve what you are looking for, you could place the code that need to be shared in a parent controller or you could create a factory (which is a singleton ) to share the data among both controllers.

You could also use events (broadcast, emit, on) to communicate controllers.